# Trying to use a conditional and return at the same time but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do this:

```
(number % 2 == 0) ? return 1 : return 0;
```

But it doesn't work, does someone know why?

Comment: You probably want `return ( (number % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0 );`

Comment: `return` is not a function but statament and brackets are not needed.

Comment: I realize that but I prefer to always put ternary operator expressions in parenthesis for clarity.

Comment: I do agree that **sometimes**, esp. in combined conditions (+ macros), using brackets is beneficial and I do that too, yet in this case there is no disambiguation - it's just regular and **simple** ternary operator. These brackets are simply useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write this way:

```
return (number % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You could also write it without the redundant parentheses.

Comment: You can also write it without the `?:` operator altogether: `return (number % 2) == 0;` This yields a boolean `true` or `false`, which is implicitly converted to `1` or `0`, respectively, if the return type is numeric.

Comment: I actually kept the brackets intentionally for readability. Also as OP seems pretty newbie, I wanted to just correct his approach only. Yet thanks for comments.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski -- sure, some people like parentheses around some subexpressions. Personally, I find it (annoying to look at parentheses) and (figure out) that they (don't affect anything).

Comment: We are aproaching "tabs vs spaces" and "vim vs emacs" area :)

Comment: @PeteBecker: The parens in this answer would be absolutely required for the code to pass review in my team. There is no reason to omit them, and they remove all doubt as to what the expression means. They also make it easier to mentally parse. You don't _need_ to "figure out that they don't affect anything". The whole point is that you don't need to "figure out" anything at all...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- shrug. They'd be rejected in my team. And, yes, you do have to figure out that they don't affect anything; you have to read them and see what they enclose, because they **might** affect what the expression means.